# How can I have a CSS3 or JQuery hover animation like this?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, effects

I want to have a hover Effect like the effect you see in the following link after click on Explore button and hover on Heart, Brain or Hand:

[**http://www.adamhartwig.co.uk/about**](http://www.adamhartwig.co.uk/about)

thanks to respond... .

Comment: anybody could not help me?